# Is it possible to send an email to a shortcode?

Tags: sms, shortcode

I know I can send an email to someone in the form of SMS, provided I know the SMS gateway details. Can the same thing be sent to a shortcode? Or do these services can handle the emails the same way SMS is handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to send an email to a shortcode. Those are restricted to sending/receiving SMS only.

However, depending on the carrier, it is possible that they have installed an SMS-Email gateway, so the users can send/receive emails from their personal numbers. My carrier used to have that service some years ago. With that service I had an email address with the format `number@carrierdomain`.

Comment: Thanks. I was pretty sure that was the case, but wanted to see if anyone else knew of something I didn't